# How to set focus on JDateChooser when frame is loaded in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser

[image]

How to show focus on date chooser when frame is loaded?

1. how could verify textfield that user can enter only date format and
2. way how could i set focus on jdatechooser icon  in swing.

code

```
private void jDateChooser2FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
        //JDateChooser2 jdc = new JDateChooser2("DD/MM/YYYY", true);
    //jDateChooser2.getDateEditor().getUiComponent().requestFocusInWindow();
  jDateChooser2.requestFocusInWindow();

}
```

source code

```
public class welcome extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "dd/MMM/YYYY ";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
    Date date = new Date();



    /**
     * Creates new form welcome
     */
    public welcome() {
        initComponents();



         sdf.setLenient(false);

         String dt = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
         System.out.println(dt);


            try  
            {  
                date = sdf.parse(dt); 
                 System.out.println(date);
            }  
            catch(ParseException pe)  
            {  
                System.out.println("pe: " + pe.getMessage());  
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();  
            }  
            jLabel3.setText(dt);
            jTextField1.setText(dt);
     }

private void jTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
   //   System.out.println("guihgio");
      if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

            System.out.println("enter press key");


              this code is not working//

      char c = evt.getKeyChar();
      if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9') ||
         (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
         (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_SLASH)))        
      {

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Valid");
           evt.consume();
      }
  }
```

MY EVENT CODE  private void jSpinner1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
            System.out.println("spiinejngyjgkur");

```
     if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        //password pwd = new password();
        //pwd.setVisible(true);










     jSpinner1.requestFocus();

       if (evt.getSource() == jSpinner1) //add
    {
        try {
            String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/indospirit";
            String uName = "root";
            String uPass = "paras123";

            //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            java.sql.Driver d = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

            PreparedStatement ps;
                System.out.println("weww");

      ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `log1`(`date`)VALUES('" + dateString + "')");

            int i = ps.executeUpdate();

            if (i > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Added");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record NOT Added");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            //ex.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex1) {
            //ex1.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(ex1.toString());
        }
    }

    try {
        String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/indospirit";
        String uName = "root";
        String uPass = "paras123";

        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        java.sql.Driver d = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from `log1` ORDER BY `date` DESC limit 1");

        while (rs.next()) {

            int col = rs.getInt("id");
            String str = rs.getString("date");

            jLabel10.setText(str);

            System.out.println(col + " " + str + " ");

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    } catch (Exception ex1) {
        System.err.println(ex1.toString());
    }

         } 


        event not working
```

private void jSpinner1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       System.out.println("gijjhbip");
         System.out.println("Source: " + evt.getSource());
    }

```
     how could  I check THAT date Enterd by user in date format in JFormattedTextField...please help  IN KEY PRESSED EVENT

       my code is here
```

private void jFormattedTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:

```
    System.out.println(evt.getKeyChar());

   if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

       Date date = (Date) evt.getSource();
      if(!(date.equals(format)))
      {
          evt.consume();
      }
   }
```

Comment: There's no point requesting focus once focus has being gained.

Comment: what event should i used so that i can used to click on datechooser icon i have tried but no success

Comment: could u please send me code for question how could i validate textfield

Comment: Maybe this one helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615958/java-gui-how-to-set-focus-on-jbutton-in-jpanel-on-jframe

Comment: jDateChooser2.requestFocusInWindow(); not working to focus on datechoser icon

Comment: If it's the field I think it is, the field is based on a JPanel with other components added to it  meaning you actually need to get down to the editor ... Which isn't public...

Comment: THIS EVENT IS NOT FIRING IF HAD CHECKED WITH SUBMIT BUTTON ITS OK AND FIRIING  ALSO.. WHERE IM WRONG

Answer (score 1):

> *"how could verify textfield that user can enter only date format and "*

IMHO getting user input for a date is vary bad idea. Validating input will become a headache and is inefficient for the program, as the user can input *any* combination of character. Instead you could use a `JSpinner` using a `DateListModel`

See [Spinner tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) | [SpinnerDateModel javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html)

---

But then again, why even allow for an input for today's date? That data can be retrieved any number of ways, other than getting the input from the user.

---

If you truly *insist* on doing your way, with the text field input and want to validate, you can always just catch a `ParseException`. but in such a situation, you would need to specify to the user exactly what format need to be inputted, and have some sort of notification for when the user input is not in a correct format or is not a real date.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimplDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
String dateString = textField.getText();
Date date;
try {
    date = formatter.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException) {
    statusLabel.setText("Please enter a valid date");
    // or JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter a valid Date");
}
```

But again a problem is that the user can input an random date like some date in 2102.  So I'd suggest either a `JSpinner` or an uneditable text field that just display today's date.

---

**UPDATE** try this

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.*;

```
public class SpinnerDateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM//yyyy");
        String dateString = formatter.format(date);
        spinner.setModel(new SpinnerListModel(new String[]{dateString}));
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, spinner, "Spinner:"
                ,JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    }
}
```

Or using the `SpinnerDateModel`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date = new Date();
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
    spinner.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, spinner, "Spinner:"
            ,JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

}
```

Comment: and please explain second question if i get focus on datechooser i could select date from calenader. i could drive problem easy .

Comment: Sorry, but I have never use `JDateChooser` so I don't know how it works.

Comment: COULD PLEaSE SENd ME THE CURRENT DATE  CODE FOR SPINNER plEASE  im new bie  to spinner

Comment: SpinnerModel snd = new SpinnerDateModel(
                new Date(),
                null,
                null,
                Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH
        );
        JSpinner spnDate = new JSpinner(snd);

Comment: HOW TO ADD SPINNER  LABEL PLS HELP. IF ADD TO SPIINER CALSS OBJ IM USING NETBAENS ERROR: UNKNOWN SYMBOL ERROR.

Comment: which event should impose on spinner class.

Comment: ChangeListener ChangeEvent

Comment: private void jSpinner1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       
           System.out.println("spii4543564578");
         System.out.println("value changed: " + jSpinner1.getValue());
    }

Comment: @user2818060: See [*How to Use Spinners*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html), and please don't shout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what library you use, but why not try this [jcalendar](http://max-server.myftp.org/trac/jcalendar).

1st question:
you can use JFormattedTextField, instand of JTextField.

```
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    DateFormatter formatter = new DateFormatter(format);  
    format.setLenient(false);  
    formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);  
    formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);  
    JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
    formattedTextField.setValue(new Date());
    formattedTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
            //System.out.println(evt.getKeyChar());
            //TODO
        }
    });
```

2nd question:
the only way of getFocuse is to change the source code of JDateChoose;
because the source code is

```
    protected JButton calendarButton;
    ...
    calendarButton = new JButton(icon) {

        public boolean isFocusable() {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: how could i set foucs on icon datechooser when frame is loaded

Comment: can anybody give answer of second question .how  could i validated textfield for  date  format...

Comment: how could check date enterd by user in date format in JFormattedTextField...please help !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for focus

```
jDateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent().requestFocusInWindow();
```

If you want to control some event

```
jDateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent().addKeyListener(new listenerClass());
```